# Grails ConfigSlurper memory leak

Tags: tomcat, grails, servlets, memory-leaks

I worked on Grails ( 2.1.0 ) project and after it's completion found out that Tomcat runs out of memory. After not very sophisticated investigation I found that following lines of code causing memory leak:

```
def servletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(servletContext.getResource('/WEB-INF/config.groovy').text)
```

Once I remove those 2 lines from my code execution, project runs on tomcat with stable memory usage. However if I bring those 2 lines back, memory usage slowly increasing.

I don't understand why those 2 lines causing memory leak? What is so magical about them? How do I fix it? I need to access resources in the WEB-INF folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is this code?  Are you parsing `config.groovy` once at startup or are you trying to parse it repeatedly in a controller action?

Comment: Code is in the Quartz schedule class. I am parsing it repeatedly once scheduled job executes.

Comment: You should find some way to parse it just once, since you're going to get the same result every time. Maybe put the parsing logic in a static block or similar.

Comment: Can you explain why is it happening? Now I am just curious.

Comment: `ConfigSlurper.parse` compiles a class every time it is called, and the memory consumed by a compiled class can't be freed until the defining classloader is GCd.

Comment: I see, let me try to use you suggestion and static it.
Actually making it static might now work then :(

Comment: Ian, please make a full answer from our discussion so I can give you a full credit. I put ConfigSlurper into BootStrap so I load config on application lunch and it seems to eliminate the issue, as you said! I will test it for a bit and then accept your answer. 
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if you really need to reparse the configuration. Have you tried `Holders.getGrailsApplication().config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in the comments that

> Code is in the Quartz schedule class. I am parsing it repeatedly once scheduled job executes.

Every time you do `ConfigSlurper.parse` it has to compile a Groovy class.  Since you are parsing a fixed script (from `/WEB-INF/config.groovy`) you will get the same result every time, so you should try and find some way to parse the file just once and store the resulting `ConfigObject` somewhere that your Quartz job can access it.

Comment: I used BootStrap to load config into memory on the application boot.